# Joomla show content article in a other article

Tags: joomla, show, article

Does anyone know if it's possible to show the content of one article in another article
?
I got a page for visitors and i got a page for members (both different template).

both have a link to the same article, is it possible to link them to the same article with keeping their own template?

I think its possible to make a new article to show the content of the original article,
but i dont know how.

Please help!

Comment: Please try to make two menu items and set the template selection there.

Comment: WOW, ofcourseeeeeeee!

Comment: searching for it about a hour and the solution is so damn easy xD

Comment: Please add your answer and accept it to mark it as solved ;)

Comment: How do i mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to make two menu items and set the template selection there.